# For WooCommerce, is it possible to have a category name appear differently by user role?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On the shop page I have...

Product Categories

- All Products
- Education
- Instructor Store

When a customer logs into the store, I would like 'Instructor Store' to change to 'Training'. The slug can stay the same, just need the category name in the HTML to change. Is that possible?

I prefer to add something to the functions.php file versus installing yet another plugin. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a small function to check if a user has a role and call it from your php template to decide what to show him. Something like this:

```
function my_has_role($user, $role) {
  $roles = $user->roles; 
  return in_array($role, (array) $roles);
}
```

This can go into your functions.php and then you can call it anywhere for a specific or current user:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if(my_has_role($user, 'Customer')) {
  //do what you want here
}
```

A similar function, if you always want to check current logged in user, would be this:

```
function my_current_user_role($role) {
 if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
   $user = wp_get_current_user();
   $roles = ( array ) $user->roles;
   return in_array($role, $roles);
 } else {
   return false;
 }
}


/* Use it like this */
if(my_current_user_role('Customer')) {
  //do what you want here
}
```